# How to model RF-PA in MATLAB when the design values are given?

Tags: rf, matlab, distortion, power-amplifier

I have been given a designed Class-E  RF-PA - the technology used for the MOSFET, the inductor and capacitor values attached to the MOSFET (as given in the figure below). I am suppossed to find the AM/AM and AM/PM distortion graphs using this information using MATLAB or Simulink.
[image]

I searched on the internet, and I could find memory polynomial block of the RF-PA (which needs input of the behavioural model of the PA) in RF-Blockset. But, I do not know how to implement my model using this available block. Is there a better way to do this? Later on, I also want to implement the DPD and memory effect - which I figured out how to do. But, I do not know how to get started.

Comment: In matlab or simulink?

Comment: Any of them would work.

Comment: Moodle it in spice then import the data for graphing

Comment: Okay, sure. I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot @VoltageSpike, your advice helped me long way in my project.